# Data sorting in an array in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to sort ascending in the desired format? Given below is the shiftdata and desired output

```
 //data is in the given below format
   shiftdata = [
        { 'Name': 'A', 'Data': '57.6' },
         { 'Name': 'B', 'Data': '-10.6' },
        { 'Name': 'C', 'Data': '50.6' },
        { 'Name': 'D', 'Data': '-5.6' },
      ];

I want to convert it in sort ascending order like(Desired output)
 shiftdata = [
       { 'Name': 'B', 'Data': '-10.6' },
       { 'Name': 'D', 'Data': '-5.6' },
       { 'Name': 'C', 'Data': '50.6' },
        { 'Name': 'A', 'Data': '57.6' },
      ];

Question2: Sort ascending the shiftdata, leaving shiftdata[0] and shiftdata[last] as it is and sort ascend inside.
```

Comment: did you try something, looking at array.sort of java script might help

Comment: Thanks for help. Updated Question2 , please suggest some solution for it too.

Comment: Please keep different questions separated, and do not edit your question to radically change it after answers have already been submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Data sorting in an array in angular2

Just like you would do it normally in vanilla js

```
shiftdata.sort( function(a,b){ return a.Data - b.Data });
console.log( shiftdata ); //sorted array
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Updated Question2 , please suggest some solution for it too

Comment: @manzerahmadhashmi this is a new question and looks good as well, please post a new question for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sort` function

```
shiftdata = shiftdata
    .sort((a,b) => a.Data > b.Data ? 1 : (a.Data < b.Data ? -1 : 0 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[sort](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)** javascript method to sort your data. This function accepts a comparation function to sort your data as you want.

In your case it would be:

```
var sortShiftdata = shiftdata.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.Data-b.Data
})
```

If you use ES6 you can use the arrow functions:

```
const sortShifdata = shiftdata.sort((a, b) => a.Data - b.Data)
console.log(sortShifdata)
```